Running Python Notebook in VS Code won't find "pynvml" module installed
I installed "pip install nvidia-ml-py" on python version 3.10.11 and 3.12.0
And I am trying to import as in notebook file in VS Code which uses 3.10.11 ikernel:
from pynvml import *

But above statement throws error:

ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[2], line 1
1 from pynvml import *
3 def print_gpu_utilization():
4     nvmlInit()


ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pynvml'

I have python versions 3.10.11 and 3.12.0 the version 3.12.0 is installed in ...user.pyenv.... and version 3.10.11 is installed in ...user\AppData.....
For 3.12.0 ikernel it is recognizing but not for 3.10.11.
Everything is installed the same way for both the versions. I check the packages under "3..\Lib\site-packages" the package present in both.
I tried installing from VS Code notebook file and also from command prompt for both the versions. Expecting that notebook ikernel "pip install" might have issue, but none worked.

If one version recognizes and another version don't recognize:
Check manually if package is installed in both versions.
If it did, then know that python uses specification file or information of a module to import it. Which you can find using the below code in both versions:
import importlib.util 
name = 'pynvml'  
spec = importlib.util.find_spec(name) 
print(spec)

This prints the path to specification file for any version of python if the file exists. So in my case 3.12.0 prints the path and 3.10.11 don't.
It might be missing from the version of python that is not recognizing the module.
Just copy and paste the file(example:
"c:\Users\user_name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pynvml.py") to the site-packages directory of python version that lacks this file.
